# Why class type has array symbol in method call

Tags: c#

I have a method which returns some values and has a type of  `AppPints()` as below:

```
  public AppPints[] GeByLatLong(int scale)
        {
            return GeByLatLong(scale);
        }
```

Why does it have a `[]` symbol within the method definitions? Why not just:

```
  public AppPints GeByLatLong(int scale)
        {
            return GeByLatLong(scale);
        }
```

Comment: The first method returns an array of `AppPints` (e.g. 0..*) while the other returns exactly one (which may, however, be `null`). Since you seem to know that the `[]` denotes an array, what is the question?

Comment: The return type declaration has an array symbol *because the method returns an array*.

Comment: Because the method returns an array of AppPints objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is returning an array of `AppPints`.